# Zoom camera on player

Tags: unity, camera

I am developing a simple side scrolling game. I want to target and zoom camera on player when he dies. But it rotates the screen, and I want to prevent it. I'm copying the snippet of code here :

```
IEnumerator ZoomIn()
{
    while (GameCamera.orthographicSize > 2) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.01f);
        GameCamera.orthographicSize -= 0.2f;
    }
}

public void ZoomCamera()
{
    CameraZoomSource.Play ();
    StartCoroutine (ZoomIn ());
}

public void TargetPlayer()
{
    transform.LookAt (PlayerTransform); 
    GameCamera.orthographicSize = 3;
    GameCamera.transform.Rotate (0, 0, -2);
}
```

Should I change anything in this?

Comment: You are rotating the Camera, why would you not expect it to rotate?

Comment: still it rotates the screen.

Comment: Are you using a script for camera to follow the player? What does CameraZoomSource.Play (); do? What's the position of the camera when the player dies?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved a problem with a simple logic. Now, When player dies, camera position will be set exact to the player position, thus focusing the camera on player. And after that the orthographic size of the camera will reduced to give it zooming effect. Here is code snippet :

```
IEnumerator ZoomIn()
{
    while (GameCamera.orthographicSize > 2) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.01f);
        GameCamera.orthographicSize -= 0.2f;
    }
}

public void ZoomCamera()
{
    StartCoroutine (ZoomIn ());
}

public void TargetPlayer()
{
    Vector3 TempCameraPos = transform.position;
    TempCameraPos.x = PlayerTransform.position.x;
    TempCameraPos.y = PlayerTransform.position.y;
    transform.position = TempCameraPos;
}
```